# Regex get section in markdown file

Tags: java, regex, markdown

I am trying to use regex to get each section of a list of links (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Anything-Minecraft-Team/anything-minecraft/main/server/info/lists/plugins/anticheats.md)

I want to be able to get each section from the list like this

```
- [Anti Cheat](https://github.com/Paroxial/Anti-Cheat)  
Version: 1.8  
Rating: ???  
Discontinued
```

so I can get the version/rating info and know what link it came from

I have `(?:.*)(?:\n .*)*` that selects text that has spaces in between above/below text (edit no it doesnt im really dumb). But due to my formatting it doesn't work, is there another way to do this or do I have to change the formatting?

Comment: Maybe this will help.  Not sure! https://regex101.com/r/tFRlrx/1

Comment: Do you need extract sections with ??? in Rating? What's your expected result from your provided input?

Comment: @MDR thanks! that nearly works, How could i be able to get if it has Discontinued, currently active or currently inactive at the end of it though?

Comment: @MajidHajibaba yes i need to get them if it has ??? too, im checking if info is out of date. I am comparing it to info that i get from an api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the link and the sections using 3 capture groups.

```
^- \[[^]\[]+]\((https?://[^\s()]+)\).*\R(Version:.*)\R(Rating:.*)\R(\S.+)$
```

- `^-`  Match `-`  at the start of the string
- `\[[^]\[]+]` Match from `[...]`
- `\((https?://[^\s()]+)\)` Match `(` and capture the url in group 1 and match `)`
- `.*\R` Match the rest of the line and a newline
- `(Version:.*)` Capture group 2, match the Version information
- `\R(Rating:.*)` Capture group 3, match the Rating information
- `\R(\S.+)$` Match a newline and capture a single whitespace char and the rest of the line in group 4

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7vFAmH/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/XxHDgv)

```
final String regex = "^- \\[[^]\\[]+]\\((https?://[^\\s()]+)\\).*\\R(Version:.*)\\R(Rating:.*)\\R(\\S.+)$";
final String string = "- [ABC Advanced Anticheat](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/91606/) - Removed due to private reasons  \n"
+ "Version: 1.7 - 1.16  \n"
+ "Rating: 4  \n"
+ "Discontinued\n"
+ "- [AbdeslamNeverCheat](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/61280)  \n"
+ "Version: 1.8  \n"
+ "Rating: 1  \n"
+ "Discontinued";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Link: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("Version: " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("Rating: " + matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println("Status: " + matcher.group(4));
}
```

Output

```
Link: https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/91606/
Version: Version: 1.7 - 1.16  
Rating: Rating: 4  
Status: Discontinued
Link: https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/61280
Version: Version: 1.8  
Rating: Rating: 1  
Status: Discontinued
```

Comment: How could I get the last line too? (Discontinued, Currently Active or Currently Inactive. It could be something else too)

Comment: @JustDoom I have updated the answer for the last part as well.